# i want to manipulate by the value which was send by php.. but the ajax is not working properly

Tags: jquery

From javascript code by onclick i call a function and sending the value through ajax to another php page.. simply make it as "s". if the sending value was "s" it want to show as "success" else "fail" but i'm getting "fail" for all correct and non correct inputs..

Javascript Code:

```
function asd()
  {
     var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
     var pass=document.getElementById("password").value;
     $.post("vi.php",{uname:uname,pass:pass,rand:Math.random() },
         function(data)
             {  
            /*type:"POST",
            url:"vi.php?uname="+uname+"&pass="+pass,

            success:function(data)
                {
              if(data=='s')
                 {
                 alert("sccess");
                 }
             else
                 {
                 alert("faile");
                 }
                }
     */
       alert(data);
       if(data=="s")
      {
             alert("hello");
      }
      else
      {
              alert("fail");
      }

   });
    }
```

PHP  CODE:

```
   <?php

      $a=$_POST['uname'];
      echo $a;


   ?>
```

OUTPUT Was:

Message Box "Fail" for all inputs...

Comment: What value does the alert box show for `data`?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="vi.php?">
username : <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" > 
password  : <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="asd()"  />
</form> hope you understand now... i need only one thing if we pass the text value as "s" it want to show as success but it keep on showing "fail"

Comment: No, I was asking for the value of this statement: `alert(data);` you have that in your code. What value does it show when the alert box pops out?

Comment: it alerting the value of "s" but while it check it showing alert "fail"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have extra whitespace in your PHP file, it that PHP code is typed as it is, then the output will have whitespace before the string that it returns